# OCaml: Expressing "set of t" in mli file

Tags: set, ocaml

New to OCaml and stumbling with Sets (really, with module types and functors). I'd like to define the following in an `.mli` file:

```
type t

type tag

val tags : t -> <set of tag>
```

where `set of tag` is the type I can't figure out, analogous to `tag list`.

UPDATE: thanks to Jeffrey Scofield for his helpful comments below, but since my real question is still unanswered, I don't think I expressed it well. Here's a second attempt:

Given this `a.ml`:

```
type tag = string

module TagSet = Set.Make (struct
  type t = tag
  let compare = String.compare
end)

type t = { name : string; tags : TagSet.t }

let empty = { name = ""; tags = TagSet.empty }

let get_tags { tags; _ } = tags
```

How do I fill in this `a.mli`?

```
type t

type tag

val empty : t

val get_tags : t -> ???
```

where `???` means "TagSet.t" while still keeping `tag` abstract, i.e. "the result of calling Set.Make with an OrderedType whose t = `tag`".

Is this possible? It seems like it must be. I'm looking for the closest thing OCaml has to Scala's `Set[T]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When beginning to explore the module system of OCaml, it is quite useful to start from the module type directly inferred by the compiler itself and amend it step by step to better fit your need.

For instance, the module inferred from your implementation is:

```
type tag = string
module TagSet :
  sig
    type elt = tag
    type t
    val empty : t
    ...
    val add_seq : elt Seq.t -> t -> t
    val of_seq : elt Seq.t -> t
  end
type t = { name : tag; tags : TagSet.t; }
val empty : t
val get_tags : t -> TagSet.t
```

(You can obtain this inferred module type from either Merlin, ocaml-lsp, utop, or `ocamlc -i path_to_file.ml`).

Starting from this point, we can remove information to make the type `tag` and `t` abstract:

```ml
type tag
type t
module TagSet :
  sig
    type elt = tag
    type t
    val empty : t
    ...
    val add_seq : elt Seq.t -> t -> t
    val of_seq : elt Seq.t -> t
  end
val empty : t
val get_tags : t -> TagSet.t
```

Then another issue is that the module type of `TagSet` is quite big and verbose. It would be nice to be able to define this signature as the module type of `Set` with element of type `tag`. Fortunately, the module `Set` defines a named signature `S` that describes the signature of the result of `Make` for this very reason. If we use this predefined signature, we can simplify the previous definition to

```ml
type tag
type t
module TagSet : Set.S with type elt = tag
val empty : t
val get_tags : t -> TagSet.t
```

Comment: Thank you! For the answer and for the lesson in how to derive it. I was almost there in my own experimentation, but I didn't know you could declare a `module` abstractly in the .mli like that, to mean "this module defines a module called `TagSet` with the following module type". Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an abstract parameterized type `'a set` in your interface:

```
type t
type tag
type 'a set
val tags : t -> tag set
```

When you write the .ml file you'll have to determine a representation and implementation for `'a set`. I.e., you need to provide a set that can have any element type.

You could also just have two abstract types, one for tags and one for a set of tags:

```
type t
type tag
type tagset
val tags : t -> tagset
```

When you code up the .ml file for this, you just need to implement a set of tags (which might be more efficient than a general set).

Comment: Thanks very much, especially for the quick reply. Do you mean that there's no way to specify that this will return an instance of the built-in set type, with all of its pre-defined operations, but for abstract type `tag`? That's what I would really like to express. `tags set` was just my notation to imply what I wanted to express, not literally what I need it to look like in the code.

Comment: If you want to use the built-in Set type, you need to apply Set.Make to get a module, that's all. There's no problem doing this other than deciding where to define the module. If you keep the interface abstract you can define the module inside your implementation.

Comment: Thank you. With this solution though, the caller couldn't use the type as a set unless I define all the operations on that type, right? I want them to be able to have all the built-in set type's operations on the returned `tagset` or `tag set` type. I updated my question to try to make my intention clearer.